# Download a Git repo from BitBucket

Tags: git, download, bitbucket

I just download Git bash and now I want to download a repository from Bitbucket. 
I have the username and password.

When I try:

```
$ git clone https://xxxxx@bitbucket.org/xxxx/xxxxx.git
```

I get:

```
Cloning into 'xxxx'...

fatal:https://xxxxx@bitbucket.org/xxxx/xxxxx/info/refs not found did you git
 update server-info on the server ?
```

Comment: Are you positive you're using the correct URL?

Comment: I got the url from bitbucket where it says Clone this repository (size: 580 bytes): HTTPS / SSH ...

Comment: Then are you positive that the repo actually exists and has been initialized?

Comment: Have you tried to use ssh instead of https? Is there any proxy/firewall in your environment, which could filter content?

Comment: You will get exactly that error message if you use a wrong URL.

Comment: The Ssh mechanism worked. Thanks Greg

Answer (score 45, accepted):

When you create a repository in bitbucket, the user interface displays the exact clone command you need for you:

[image: capture of clone help]

So, your clone command would need to be:

https://**usersname**@bitbucket.org/**username**/reponame.git

Answer (score 9):

you can also use ssh to clone, this allows for the setup of passwordless push and pulling, with the use of ssh keys.

git clone git@bitbucket.org:username/reponame.git

Answer (score 6):

*Bitbucket* may use *Mercurial*. Are you really cloning a **git** repository? I solved the same problem by cloning with *hg* ;-)

Answer (score 3):

the interface on bitbucket has changed, so people looking for the right command can find it on the left hand side under "Actions"->"Clone" and you'll see the command already coded for https. It works.

Comment: Thanks, this change made it even less intuitive.